# Tkinter Treeview cannot edit more that one column

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, ubuntu-12.04

I use a Tkinter TreeView that I populate with data from a file.

The result is 6 columns of prefilled numeric data for each row.
Some rows has a single column value, others has multiple columns filled with data, editable by the user (upon mouse right click).

For rows with single editable column, I use the following piece of code:

```
...
self.tree.insert(id2 , 2,    text=key2.strip('\r\n'), \
  values=("","","10","","",""), \
  tags=('','','tag3','','',''))
  self.tree.tag_bind(('','','tag3','','',''), '<Button-3>', self.popupEntry)
...
```

**Result: (OK)**
If right click then dialogbox popup with text entry, upon validation, the column of he corresponding row is **successfully** filled with the new value. This works for any single value tuple "tags".

But, for rows with more that one editable column I modified the previous code as follow:

```
...
self.tree.insert(id2 , 2,    text=key2.strip('\r\n'), \
  values=("","","10","","","10"), \
  tags=('','','tag3','','','tag6'))
  self.tree.tag_bind(('','','tag3','','','tag6'), '<Button-3>', self.popupEntry)
...
```

**Result: (Not OK)**
No reaction to mouse Right click, nothing happens

**Desired behavior:**
- for rows with 2 or more editable columns, right-click to spawn dialogbox with 2 text entries, upon validation, the 2 column values are filled.

Something like that:
[image]

**Popup code:**

```
   def popupEntry(self, event):
        result = tkSimpleDialog.askinteger("New value", "Please enter a new numeric value")
        if result:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.focus(), values=self.tag_to_val(self.tree.item(self.tree.focus(), 'tags'), result))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind to a group of tags like that. You must create a binding for each individual tag.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I also used the answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467437/tkinter-parent-to-child-data-exchange) to update both values using child window.