# Tkinter parent to child data exchange

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I hope it is not a duplicate question as a solution has been proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718073/how-to-create-child-window-and-communicate-with-parent-in-tkinter/10718548#comment47050170_10718548), which I have a hard time making it work. (Alternatively I could post this in the same discussion)

**Goal:**

In the main window the user enter some data, if clicked, a new child window appears with parent data, eventually operates on them, then sends back the result to parent widgets.

[image]

**Code used:**

```
from Tkinter import *

class trackApp(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.mainVar1 = IntVar()
        self.mainVar2 = IntVar()

        self.mainVar1.set(100)
        self.mainVar2.set(100)
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('400x200+100+200')
        self.master.title('MAIN WINDOW')

        self.label1=Label(self.master,text='Variable1 : ').grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.mainEntry1=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.mainVar1).grid(row=1,column=2)

        self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Variable2 : ').grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.mainEntry2=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.mainVar2).grid(row=2,column=2)

        self.button1=Button(self.master,text='Child',command=self.dialogWindow).grid(row=7,column=2)


    def new_data(self, data):
        self.mainEntry1.delete(0,END)
        self.mainEntry1.insert(0,self.data['var1'])
        self.mainEntry2.delete(0,END)
        self.mainEntry2.insert(0,self.data['var2'])


    def dialogWindow(self):
        # Build a list from control variables used in the main window text entry boxes
        mainList = [self.mainVar1.get(),self.mainVar2.get()]

        top=Toplevel(self.master)
        childDialog=childWindow(top,mainList, self.master)


class childWindow(Frame):

    # Pass data (list) to the child
    def __init__(self, master, list, app):

        self.list = list

        self.app = app
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('300x100+150+250')
        self.master.title('CHILD WINDOW')

        # Define control variabels to be used with child window text entry widgets
        self.childvar1 = IntVar()
        self.childvar2 = IntVar()

        # Fill child window text entry widgets with inf. from parent window
        self.childvar1.set(list[0])
        self.childvar2.set(list[1])

        # Text entry widgets
        self.label1=Label(self.master,text='Enter New value 1').grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.childEntry1=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.childvar1).grid(row=0,column=2)

        self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Enter New value 2').grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.childEntry2=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.childvar2).grid(row=1,column=2)

        self.button1=Button(self.master,text='OK',command=self.childDestroy).grid(row=3,column=1)


    def childDestroy(self):

        self.data = {}
        self.data['var1'] = self.childvar1.get()
        self.data['var2'] = self.childvar2.get()

        trackApp.app.new_data(self, self.data)  # <<<<<<<<< How to call the parent new_data method

        self.master.destroy()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = trackApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Question:**

How to refer to the parent method (**new_data**) from the child?

**Error:**

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /<path>/child-dialog.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/<path>/child-dialog.py", line 77, in childDestroy
    trackApp.app.new_data(self, self.data)  # <<<<<<<<< How to call the parent new_data method
AttributeError: class trackApp has no attribute 'app'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is: it says that `trackApp` has no attribute `'app'`, and looking at the definition of that class I see no attribute `'app'`.

For your child window to know it's parent, you need to give it a reference to the parent. So, when creating the window you pass the reference in, and within the child window you use the reference.

It looks like you're attempting to do that, but you're passing in the wrong value, and then you're not using the value. You need to modify your code to look like this:

```
class trackApp(Frame):
    ...
def dialogWindow(self):
    ...
    childDialog=childWindow(top,mainList, self)

class childWindow(Frame):
    def childDestroy(self):
        ...
        self.app.new_data(self, self.data) 
        ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Bryan for the answer. Here are the changes I have made accordingly:

Pass the parent (self) to the child window

```
def dialogWindow(self):
    childDialog=childWindow(top,mainList, self)
```

Call the parent method using parent instance (self)

```
def childDestroy(self)    
    self.app.new_data(self.data)
```

and the following to update main window widgets:

```
def new_data(self, data):
    self.mainVar1.set(data['var1'])
    self.mainVar2.set(data['var2'])
```

Appreciate your help.